# Google developer console auth API

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

Does anyone know if there is an API to access the Credentials section in API&auth on Google developers console? I looked everywhere without any luck.
I would like to programatically change the Redirect URIs in my registered web application.

Comment: Sorry, that is not possible.